# How to save all used variables between functions in R

Tags: r, function, global-variables

I would like to run function X and store all variables used in this function into my environment so that I can access them straight from the console or other scripts. I know, it is not recommended to use global variables, but I need it to improve the code.

Example:

Toy.R

```
executeToy <-function(time){
X = 2+time
W = 2
}
```

ToyCall.R

```
source('Toy.R')
Y = X+2
```

Comment: Global variables don't improve the code. Let your functions return all variables that you want to use outside of them.

Comment: How do I return variables?

Comment: One possibility is to return a list containing all variables of interest. If you want an example, you need to expand your question.

Comment: I included a small example. Could you show me how to edit Toy.R to 1)return variable X and 2)how to return all variable from Toy.R

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you planning to use this? It's not common to return local variables from a function, the point is to return a value which represents something.

Comment: I am using code from somebody else and I would like to run it for different conditions, however I want to see what happens to all variables, so that I can improve or rewrite the code easier. I matlab this workflow is not a big deal, but I am new to R...

Comment: @C.Colden Have a look at `help("browser")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This returns a list of all variables in the functions environment:

```
executeToy <-function(time){
  X = 2+time
  W = 2
  mget(ls())
}

executeToy(1:3)
#$time
#[1] 1 2 3
#
#$W
#[1] 2
#
#$X
#[1] 3 4 5
```

However, from your comments I believe the `browser` function (which steps through an expression, i.e., is usually used for debugging) would be more useful to you.

Example:

```
executeToy <-function(time){
  browser()
  X = 2+time
  W = 2
  X
}
```

Then call the function:

```
> executeToy(1:3)
Called from: executeToy(1:3)
Browse[1]> time
[1] 1 2 3
Browse[1]> n
debug at #3: X = 2 + time
Browse[2]> n
debug at #4: W = 2
Browse[2]> X
[1] 3 4 5
Browse[2]> n
debug at #5: X
Browse[2]> W
[1] 2
Browse[2]> n
[1] 3 4 5
```

Comment: Great! This helps a lot in combination with the return command!

Answer (score 1):

To return all variables from Toy.R in a list:

```
executeToy <-function(time){
X = 2+time
W = 2
result <- list(ls()) #updated
return(result)
}
```

If you want to return only X:

```
executeToy <-function(time){
X = 2+time
W = 2
return(X)
}
```

Comment: Posiibly you also need to show them how to use a function. I'm not sure they know how that works.

Comment: @beginneR Thank you for the 'return' command. This works well for one or a few variables. Is there a way to return all variables?

Comment: if you run for example `result <- executeToy(inoutdata)` and your function returned a list (like the first example in my answer) you can then access the variables by using `result$X` and `result$W`